# Grab it if it's there, forget it if it's not Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm parsing a file with address details. Sometimes the address has one fax number, sometimes it has two fax numbers (on separate lines). How can I say "If there's a second fax number, grab it. If not, forget it" to my regex engine?

Here's an example with one fax number:

> Tel: +1 212 12345
>   Fax: +1 212 23456
>
> District HQ: Springfield

and with two fax numbers:

> Tel: +1 212 12345
>   Fax: +1 212 23456
>   Fax: +1 212 34567
>
> District HQ: Springfield

I'm using PHP's `preg_match_all` to get matches:

```
$shop_name_regexp = 
        '/' . 
        'Tel.*?:(?<telephone>.*?)\n' . // Tel: or Telephone:
        'Fax:(?<fax>.*?)\n.*?' .
        '/s';
preg_match_all($shop_name_regexp, $string, $hit);
```

I thought I could grab the second fax number with something like `[Fax:(?<fax2>.*?)]?` but I can't get it working. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it :)

```
$shop_name_regexp = 
    '/' . 
    'Tel.*?:(?<telephone>.*?)\n' . // Tel: or Telephone:
    'Fax:(?<fax>.*?)\n\s*?' .
    '(Fax:(?<fax2>.*?))?\n.*?' .
    '/s';
preg_match_all($shop_name_regexp, $string, $hit);
```

The square brackets indicate a character class. So to match a, b, or c you would use square brackets: [abc]. To create a optional group you use parens.